# Change Base view controller object in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a base view controller in my ios app and all other viewcontrollers inherits from it. I have created a custom navigation bar in this base view controller. Now need to change a image in the navigation bar which was defined in base view view controller. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

If you create BaseViewController in AppDelegate.m file, and added it to Window, you can access it from other controllers using delegate like

```
AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Just Import AppDelegate.h

now del.yourBaseViewController is accessble in other view controllers.

Make BaseViewController member of AppDelegate.

If your BaseViewController is not in AppDelegate, then you have to pass its reference to ChildViewControllers to access it.

And then you can access object of NavigationBar of BaseViewController.

Regards.